# How to avoid excel file format alert while opening an exported excel file?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, excel

Iam exporting html data to excel. I am getting an excel file as soon as i click on export button but when i try to open the excel file an alert is popping up saying that the file format is different from the extension specified. how can i get rid of this alert, please help me Iam using the following code

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 600
```

Comment: I'd try a CSV instead: `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv"`

Comment: Or use the epplus package to export to a native xlsx file

Comment: I've tried "text/csv" it is exporting the aspx page with html tags, I want an excel file to be exported here. @Daniel Cook

Comment: Look up "extension hardening".  There are a few options you could set on your own machine, but if you have other users this will not be an option.  Basically you cannot send content which does not match the extension you set.  If you're saying it's an Excel file then it must be an **actual** Excel file (ie. not just HTML)

Comment: Only the data is exported in Rows in excel file, no html tags are exported into it. how can we set the content to match the extension here ? @Tim Williams

Comment: You haven't shown any code, so of course I'm mostly guessing what you're actually doing.  Try posting the code which produces the output.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Try .csv format. It works for me.

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();

        string filename = "testExportToCSV";
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Customers");

        DataRow row1, row2, row3;

        DataColumn colName = new DataColumn("CustomerName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        DataColumn colCity = new DataColumn("City", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        table1.Columns.Add(colName);
        table1.Columns.Add(colCity);

        row1 = table1.NewRow();
        row1["CustomerName"] = "aa";
        row1["City"] = "ss";
        table1.Rows.Add(row1);

        row2 = table1.NewRow();
        row2["CustomerName"] = "bb";
        row2["City"] = "sdd";
        table1.Rows.Add(row2);

        row3 = table1.NewRow();
        row3["CustomerName"] = "cc";
        row3["City"] = "dfgfgf";
        table1.Rows.Add(row3);

        //foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table1.Columns)
        //{
        for (int i = 0; i < table1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            context.Response.Write(table1.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty) + ",");

        }
        context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);

        //}

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < table1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                context.Response.Write(row[i].ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty) + ",");
            }

            context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".csv");
        context.Response.End();

    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

i had work on your issue but i have found that its `security issue` and its became bad impact on your `system's security if we modify it`.

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security
Value: (DWORD)"ExtensionHardening" = 
                         [0 = Disable check; 
                          1 = Enable check and prompt; 
                          2 = Enable check, no prompt deny open]

Default setting if value not present is 1 (enable and prompt).
```

You can refer whole article from this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

**EDIT 2:** `Steps to Modify Registry...`

1. Click **Start Menu**
2. In Search Program and files type **run**
3. Then type **REGEDIT**, press OK
4. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security

Hope, it will helps you. !! Thanks.

If it solves your problem then mark it as answer so that other can also refer it.

Comment: I found no answer in the link you have provided @Mack28

Comment: Cathode - you first refer 2 links which i have provided in my answer.

Comment: I have gone through them and tried some of the solutions which helped me in no way. I am not using any gridview in my code. I am just creating a table and exporting it to excel

Comment: I am using the same code in my file, its still giving me the alert :( @Mack28

Comment: i'm edited my answer and find out the reason that causes that alert message. You can read whole article i have added link.

Comment: thank you @Mack28, In my PC I found till HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0 I did not find Excel in 12.0 Folder instead i have a folder with name 'common'

Comment: thank you Mack@28, I have set it to 0 and tried again. I have received the same alert even after setting it to 0.